# Openstack autopilot test drive alternative to vsphere?

Tags: server, vmware, openstack-autopilot, cluster

I want to try openstack with autopilot test drive and I am trying to setup a cluster with vms.
VSphere is not supported on ubuntu server is there any other alternative that I can use or somehow make vsphere work on linux??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. Do you have ESX servers that you can connect to vsphere? Or, when you say vsphere is not supported in ubuntu, do you mean the client part?

If it's just the client, then indeed you are out of luck. I suggest to download an official Windows VM image from http://dev.modern.ie and use IE inside it to access vsphere and set things up.

Otherwise, if you have machines with enough RAM, you could create VMs in them with virt-manager, register them with MAAS as if they were bare metal machines, and use that to install a) the autopilot; and b) the cloud, using autopilot.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am trying to make it work with virtualbox now...